# How to Customise AutoCompleteTextView in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am trying to Customise the look of AutoCompleteTextView  i need a rounded Entry

till now i have tried this

```
 [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AutoCompleteViewv3), 
 typeof(AutoCompleteViewRendererv3))]
namespace PredictiveList.Droid
{
 public class AutoCompleteViewRendererv3  : ViewRenderer<AutoCompleteViewv3, 
  AutoCompleteTextView>
{
    static string[] COUNTRIES = new string[] {
  "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Andorra",
  "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antarctica", "Antigua and Barbuda", };

    public AutoCompleteViewRendererv3(Android.Content.Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<AutoCompleteViewv3> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null || this.Element == null)
            return;

        // var textInputLayout = (TextInputLayout)LayoutInflater.From(Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.TextInputLayout, null);

        var autoComplete = new AutoCompleteTextView(Context);
        autoComplete.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.rounded_cornersrev);


        //var autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView)LayoutInflater.From(Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.TextInputLayout, null);
        //var  txtSearch = (AutoCompleteTextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.autocomplete_country);
        // TextView name = (TextView)Android.Views.View.FindViewById(Resource.Id.txt_searchhh);
        AutoCompleteTextView textView = new AutoCompleteTextView(Context);
        textView = FindViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(Resource.Id.autocomplete_country);
        var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Context, Resource.Layout.list_item, COUNTRIES);
        autoComplete.Adapter = adapter;
        SetNativeControl(autoComplete);
    }

    // Use the control here.
    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if (this.Element == null || this.Control == null)
            return;

        // variable this.Control is the AutoCompleteTextView, so you an manipulate it.
    }
}
```

}

i am trying to implement this in Xamarin Forms if someone have some other idea please do suggest

[image]

also please help me how can i remove understroke of entry

Comment: I know it should be late, create a custom render class for entry in each platform

Comment: You can set textView's backgroud be null to remove this stroke.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try this way:

```
AutoCompleteTextView textView = new AutoCompleteTextView(textView =FindViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(Resource.Id.autocomplete_country);

textView.Background = null; // Set background be null
```

[image: have stroke]

[image: no stroke]